# Rails sudden text area height increase when input begins

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

In the view:

```
<%= f.text_area :content, rows: 2, class: "notice_area" %>
```

I have the following javascript that adjusts the height of the text area to the number of lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function h(e) {
    $(e).css({'height':'auto','overflow-y':'hidden'}).height(e.scrollHeight);
  }
  $('.notice_area').each(function () {
    h(this);
  }).on('input', function () {
    h(this);
  });
</script>
```

The css:

```
.notice_area {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 46px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The problem is that when you start typing in the text area, the height suddenly increases from the default 46px by whatever the value of padding-top, in this case 3px. It's a small thing, but incredibly annoying. When padding-top is set to 0px it's fine.
I don't see why the height doesn't stay at 46px when you start typing.
Why is this happening? I've tried everything to prevent it but no luck.

Comment: Why do you need the .height(e.scrollHeight)  when your already setting it's height by css? If you truly believe that the padding amount (3px) is what the adjustment is then you might try putting this style on your .notice_area class ... box-sizing: border-box;

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I've been unable to replicate the whole behavior in a lab environment. You might want to take a peek: http://jsfiddle.net/L9b9tdbu/1/.

But it seems to me that the problem lies in the fact that scrollHeight includes padding. So you're getting it and assigning it to height, essentially putting in the padding again, and that makes the text area grow by 3 pixels.

If I were you, I'd try to change the code to:

```
function h(e) {
  $(e).css({'height':'auto','overflow-y':'hidden'}).height(e.scrollHeight-3);
}
$('.notice_area').each(function () {
  h(this);
}).on('input', function () {
  h(this);
});
```

I.e. subtract all the padding applied before setting the height.

Hope it helps!